# C# Frequency Distribution Associative Container Initialization-way to avoid hashing twice

Tags: c#, dictionary, hash, counter

Some background. There is a `class Card`, it has an `enum` called `RANK`, and a member `Rank` of type `RANK`. The goal is to take an `IEnumerable<Card>`, and produce a dictionary like object, `Key`ed by `RANK` and `Value`d by the number of such rank in the argued sequence. 
eg. in the context of Poker, a five card sequence with quad Aces would yield an order-variant `{(ACE,4),(someOtherRank,1)}` dictionary. Below is the function that I have.

```
static IReadOnlyDictionary<Card.RANK, int> GetRankDistribution(IEnumerable<Card> hand)

    {
        var distribution = new Dictionary<Card.RANK, int>(13);

        foreach (Card.RANK rank in hand.Select(card => card.Rank))
        {
            distribution.TryGetValue(rank, out var valueBuffer);
            distribution[rank] = valueBuffer + 1;
        }

        return distribution;
    }
```

My problem is this function is called an inordinate amount of times, and allthough the dictionary is optimally sized for the domain, I cannot conceive of a way to avoid hashing twice to build the object(once in the TryGet, and once to apply the value, whether incremented off `int()` or a functional `++`).

In C++, I could `++dictionary[rank];` in the loop body. If the `Key` is absent, it is inserted, with the default `Value`constructed in situ, and its reference returned(the eventual operand of the precrement™).

In Python, I could just `return Counter(hand)`, and who knows what happens, but it is at least syntactically elegant.

**Is there any way in C#, given the most primitive of value types, to effectively achieve what the C++ map operator[](for better or worse) does?**

If inheriting and refactoring are involved in the answer, I personally do not consider it 'effective' as I define it.

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

```
var dictionary = hand.GroupBy(x => x.Rank).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```

Comment: I feel this kind of compromises the amortized constant time of using a hash map class container in the first place. `GroupBy` will do a partial sort, linear in complexity at best, three `delegate`s have to be allocated each time the expression is used, and then `Count` will iterate the grouped sequence `sequence.Length` times, yielding quadratic penalty. If it was unclear,  my goal was not to reduce the function to an expression(the Python example may have been misleading), it was to improve on the performance profile of the original function

Comment: I looked up the documentation on `GroupBy`, and the sequence it returns is already clustered, so my quadratic supplement point in the argument above is invalid, but the LINQed Count will still carry a minor penalty, and the delegate allocations are a serious cause for concern. I am honestly looking for a silver bullet here, a clandestine Counter class designed for this purpose as there is in Python

Comment: but what is your problem? is it too slow or you think it WILL be too slow? I used this on sets of 100k elements in the past, it took few milliseconds. Is performance problem something you have measured? This is "the way to go" is C# world and in almost all cases it is fast enough. If you want faster program at all, drop `IEnumerable<Card>` and use `Dictionary`

Comment: and they aren't really delegats, they are expressions. You can store them in static variables if you really want, but I don't think it would make much difference. Count has linear complexity, which is more than fine for a deck of cards

Comment: To answer your first point, yes I have measured, and maybe its too slow. The Profiler determined that 30% of all execution time in a debug build was spent in the confines of my example function, and it is a very small leaf of the call tree, but also a common one. I am not willing to forgo the maintainability generics offer. I also realize a `[] get` operator that can mutate the collection is very dangerous. I just love what it offers when it isn't debilitating codebases.

Comment: if it is called very often of course it will take a lot of percentage time. If this is really a problem, I think you should just store the decks in `Dictionary<Card.RANK, int>` all the way, or even create a `Deck` class that stores them in Dictionary and keeps count of all cards as a property. What is the average time of single invocation? Maybe the solution is to call it less?

Comment: As to your point about their not being delegates, the LINQ functions don't accept 'expression' parameters, since such parameter types don't exist. If a `Func` or `Action` is requested, it will be delivered, and at runtime cost. Even if locally defined, they will still be hoisted, because that's how LINQ works. This is off topic though.

Comment: Although you haven't directly answered my question, you have increased my confidence that the double hash is likely as viable as any other equal effort solution. I thank you for your input, I'll let the question marinate, and if the situation remains, I'll upvote you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187237/discussion-between-schulmaster-and-krzysztof-skowronek).

Comment: I've found [this](https://talkdotnet.wordpress.com/2017/11/27/net-lookup-compared-to-dictionary/). Maybe this will help you, seems like ToLookup() is a tad faster

Comment: This, in its current form, should not be an 'answer'. [Please read SO 'good answer' guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)